# Why is e.ctrlKey not work?

Tags: javascript

I want achieve a function that browser will alert one window when I keydown ctrlKey whenever.
because body element is not unfold, so I choose html element as target.

```
<html id = "body">
```

It can work.

```
var el = document.getElementById("body");
el.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
        alert("success!");
    },false);
```

But It can't work when I add ctrlKey.

```
var el = document.getElementById("body");
el.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
    if(e.ctrlKey == 1){
        alert("success!");
    }},false);
```

I think the problem is focus. But how can solve it.

Comment: I think `e` is wrong (`event` variable....) you are using `event` in your function...

Comment: Thank you! I use e because I write it in a function before and it not work. But what amazing is it can work when I try again. Thank you whatever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `window` instead of `html` tag

try:

`window.addEventListener('keydown',function,true );`

Answer (score 0):

You should use window instead of body and change the if statment to use event instead of e:

```
if(event.ctrlKey == 1){
```